# Laravel: hasMany get values from parent table also

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-many

I am a student and new in laravel.

I am using hasmany its working fine but its only showing me the result of attendance table for exampble in user table George have 5 entries in attendance table its working fine but i also want to show the name of user and all details of user which is available in user table

below is my code:

AttendanceController:

```
 $attendance = Attendance::with('users')->WhereIn('aid',$arr)->get();
```

Attendance Model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Attendance','aid','aid');
}
```

result:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "aid": 1,
    "date_in": "2018-08-03",
    "start": "09:27:00",
    "end": "18:27:00",
    "time_long": "08:59:00",
    "created_at": "2018-08-23 06:39:27",
    "updated_at": "2018-08-23 06:39:27",
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "aid": 1,
            "date_in": "2018-08-03",
            "start": "09:27:00",
            "end": "18:27:00",
            "time_long": "08:59:00",
            "created_at": "2018-08-23 06:39:27",
            "updated_at": "2018-08-23 06:39:27"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what are the columns on user table ?

Comment: aid,id, name, email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationship is wrong. It should be a User hasMany attendances and not the other way round.

Attendance Model:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

User Model:

```
public function attendances(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Attendance', 'user_id');
}
```

Then with your `$userId`, do this:

```
$attendances = App\User::find($userId)->attendances;
```

In response to your question:

I suppose you already have your $userId right?. 
In your UserController, you can do:

```
$user = User::find($userId);    //Find the user that has that id
```

Let's assume you want to use it in your view. Then do this:

```
return view('view-name', ['user' => $user]);    //pass $user to view
```

In your view, do this:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($user->attendances as $attendance)      <!--$user->attendances - You remember this?-->
        <li>{{ $user->name }} came to work on {{ $attendance->id }}</li>     <!--$user->name, $attendance->id - You can always get any other user/attendance attribute you want-->
    @endforeach
</li>
```

You can check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart-intermediate) for more insight.

Comment: is that possible to show username with each row, for example if user georges have 5 rows in attendance table... currently its showing username and than all 5 entries of related to George I want to show george name with each row

Comment: How come you copy and paste my answer ?

Comment: @MuhammadKazim ... I have edited my answer to answer your question.

Comment: @Leorent ... My solution is different from yours. Please go through it again.

Answer (score 1):

Your attendance relationship model is wrong, it should be in a relation with user model class and not with itself like you currently have:

Attendance Model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Attendance','aid','aid');
}
```

Should be pointing to user model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Users');
}
```

Since when u eager load the user it should return user data also.